# Normal Map shades the object flat

Tags: uv, normal-map, shadows

my model as a problem and as far as my knowledge goes, I can't think of a reason for this to be happening. Whenever I apply a bump/normal map, I can see the quads in the mesh after rendering. I've shaded the object smooth, texture is set to non color data, uv is properly unwrapped. It just doesn't seem to work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using a Normal Map (Blueish, in Tangent Space) or a Height Map (B/W)? . If it's a Normal Map, it should be used with a Normal Map node, not a Bump node.

Comment: Can you post a pictur e of your whole shader node setup?

Comment: Yea, im using a grayscale map for noise, here it is https://imgur.com/a/W5R6tlT